# IBM WAS 8.5 restart on error

Tags: java, jsp, websphere

We have an application which was deployed on WAS 7.5 and it would run into the issue `out of heap memory` exception it would automatically restart. After migrating it to WAS 8.5 with the same error it won't restart. Is this a known issue with WAS 8.5 or there is some configuration option to be set for WAS 8.5?

The application is built using java/JSP. We are working on fixing memory leaks on the application. We also need to solve the above configuration problem.

Let me know if some more information is required, will edit the question posted.

Comment: I know this as a function on the jdk. There is a parameter on the java runtime to run a script in case of an OOM situation. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check the same,. Will try to add it in our server. I will keep the question open for some time to check for other alternative parallel working on this one.

Comment: hi, thst can u add the comment this as the answer below, your solution seems to be working ... did not find anything more

Comment: done as requested :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this as a function on the jdk. There is a parameter on the java runtime to run a script in case of an OOM situation. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABCBGHF

`-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError`:

> -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=string
>
> Sets a custom command or a series of semicolon-separated commands to run when an OutOfMemoryError exception is first thrown. If the
>   string contains spaces, then it must be enclosed in quotation marks.
>   For an example of a command string, see the description of the
>   -XX:OnError option.
>
> -XX:OnError=string
>
> Sets a custom command or a series of semicolon-separated commands to run when an irrecoverable error occurs. If the string contains
>   spaces, then it must be enclosed in quotation marks.
>
> The following example shows how the -XX:OnError option can be used to run the userdump.exe utility to obtain a crash dump in case of an
>   irrecoverable error (the %p designates the current process):
>
> -XX:OnError="userdump.exe %p"
>
> The preceding example assumes that the path to the userdump.exe
>   utility is specified in the PATH environment variable.